# Custom binary counter supports only increment in $2^i$ values amortized analysis

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, amortized-analysis

I'm a having trouble analyzing this algorithm.
This is a binary counter that supports only increments in $2^i$ values
it's implemented in this way:
starting from the $i$-th location change all the straight $1$'s to $0$'s and the first $0$ to $1$.

So I analyzed the W.C to be $O(\log n)$ because the worst case is we need to increment by $1$ a $2^i-1$ number.
Now for the amortized I thought using the accounting method, charging for each change from $0$ to $1$ $2\$$ amortized cost, since each time we increment we flip at most one $0$ to $1$. and put $1\$$ on each $1$ bit to pay from flipping it back to $0$. so at most the amortized cost is $2\$$ which means amortized $O(n)$. if it's correct than what's the difference from a regular binary counter? I don't think I understand...

Comment: Your counter seems to be an ordinary counter that ignores the $i$ least significant bits.

Answer (score 0):

The counter you describe is a completely ordinary counter with an extra "appendage" which consists of the $i$ least significant bits. Those are never accessed by the algorithm, and the rest of the bits operate like an ordinary counter.

Comment: I already realized that, as I said in my question. But is there any difference in the amortize calculation than an ordinary counter?

Comment: It's the same as an ordinary counter, so why would there be?